# How to pass information between different web page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi everyone I am trying to pass information between diferent page, but I don't know how.

I have this form with Html.ActionLink inside

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Envi"))
    {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.Label("Description:")%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBox("info", lp.Description)%>
     ...
            <div>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Change Image", "ChangeImg", "Envi", new {id=lp}, new {id="cambio"})%>
   ...
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" name="<%= lp.Id %>"/>
            </p>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

When I click the Html.ActionLink I show other page (dialog with fancyBox) where I select an Image.

I want to pass all data from the Form to this page. Now when I show the form again I have the new data, no the old data.
How can I do that???

Thanks.

Comment: The contoller that calls this view again needs to pas the correct model to it, containing the data you want it to display.  If that's not enough information, also post the controller code for the "Save" and "ChangeImg" Views.  (There should be 4 controller methods total, 2 HttpGet and 2 HttpPost)

Answer (score 0):

You are suggested to use `TempData` dictionary. This will be available for only the next request.

Quoting from MSDN:

> An action method can store data in the controller's TempDataDictionary
>   object before it calls the controller's RedirectToAction method to
>   invoke the next action. The TempData property value is stored in
>   session state. Any action method that is called after the
>   TempDataDictionary value is set can get values from the object and
>   then process or display them. The value of TempData persists until it
>   is read or until the session times out. Persisting TempData in this
>   way enables scenarios such as redirection, because the values in
>   TempData are available beyond a single request.

Hope this gives your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I believe the form should submit to a single action.

So the controller may look like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ItemModel itemModel, string submit)
    {
        //I'm not sure why I need this but the fields display with empty results on my machine otherwise
        ModelState.Clear();

        if (submit == "edit")
        {
            this.TempData.Add("item", itemModel);
            return View("ChangeImage", new ImageModel { ImageName = itemModel.ImageName }); 
        }
        else
        {
            //perform save here
            return RedirectToAction("ViewAfterSavePerformed");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Image(ImageModel imageModel)
    {
        ItemModel itemModel = (ItemModel)this.TempData["item"];
        itemModel.ImageName = imageModel.ImageName;
        return View("Index", itemModel);
    }
}
```

With the following view models:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}

public class ImageModel
{
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

And the following views:

**Index:**

```
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Description: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)</p>
    <p>Image: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ImageName)</p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="edit" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" />
}
```

**Change Image:**

```
<h2>ChangeImage</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Image", "Home"))
{
    <p>Image: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ImageName)</p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save image" />
}
```

Hopefully this should may sense even though i've used razor syntax.